# Azure Change Tracking/Inventory (Configuration Management) cannot be enabled

Tags: azure

We have an several VMs connected to the Log Analytics workspace and the automation is linked to it. The Update Management is enabled on all VMs and it's working properly.

When trying to enable either the Change Tracking or Inventory in the Configuration Management, it's showing "Cannot enable" status. As far as I  know both the Update Management and Configuration Management use the same Agent, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Did I miss something here? If you have any Idea of what is the reason, please share it with me.

Here is the error of the deployment:

```
OPERATION ID  *****
TRACKING ID  *****
STATUS  BadRequest
STATUS MESSAGE  {
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": ""
  }
}
PROVISIONING STATE  Failed
TIMESTAMP  11.6.2019, 14:11:42
DURATION  1 second
TYPE  Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/configurationScopes
RESOURCE ID  *******/MicrosoftDefaultScopeConfig-ChangeTracking
RESOURCE  som-workspace/MicrosoftDefaultScopeConfig-ChangeTrac
```

[image]

Comment: so ugh, no error is shown?

Comment: The only  error message I am getting is "Deployment Failed" with the follow message:
Deployment to resource group '*****' failed.
Additional details from the underlying API that might be helpful: At least one error occurred while deploying resources. List the deployment processes to see details. For more information about usage, visit https://aka.ms/arm-debug.